# Sum of list of lists of lists based on indexes

Tags: python, list, sum, list-comprehension

I have a dataset as follow:

```
[['HG00096', [15, 1, 0]], ['HG00097', [33, 0, 0]], ['NA21127', [24, 1, 0]]]
```

And I would like to have to sum of the first values in the list of each list (i.e. 15 + 33 + 24 = 72).
So far, using list comprehension and with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008237/summing-a-list-of-lists-of-lists) post, I tried this line but with no success.

```
[sum([x[1][0] for x in i]) for i in testdic]
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you just want `sum(sub[1][0] for sub in data)`

Comment: Indeed, thanks.. looks so much easier and logic this way !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through the elements of each sublist, then trying to still index twice, meaning you end up indexing an int.

Instead you can simply apply your index to each element of the list.

```py
sum(x[1][0] for x in testdic)
```